# Why encrypt message digest in digital signature?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, key, signature

I am trying to understand the following:

Why should a message digest in cryptography be encrypted with the private key from the sender?

The receiver can decrypt it with the public key of the sender, but anyone else can do that too. Even the man in the middle, so I don't really see the point of encrypting the message digest in the sense of Digital Signature.

Comment: It's a digital signature; it's supposed to be verifiable by everyone. It isn't a secret.

Comment: This has been answered on the cryptography site. But in general, even though e.g. RSA uses the same operation for encryption and digital signature generation (i.e. modular exponentiation) doesn't mean that modular exponentiation with the private key equals encryption. They made this mistake in the initial version of the PKCS#1 RSA standard, but that has been corrected in all the followup versions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about programming, it is about cryptography, where it has been [asked and answered](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15997/1172) (both by me, as it got asked a lot here on SO)

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk Thank you for your response. But why would you want to exncrypt the 'message digest'?

Person A uses the public key of Person B to encrypt the mesaage and uses his own private key to encrypt the message digest. Person B decrypts the message with it's own private key and decrypts the message digest with the public key of person A. Now person B will make a hash value of the message to compare it to the message digest. I don't understand why the message digest has to be encrypted? Can you please elaborate a little on this.

Comment: It's a mistake to use the word "encryption" to refer to the signing operation of RSA. It just confuses you to do so. So don't do it. Use the word "sign". Digital signatures are "signed" and then "verified", those are the core operations. Not "encrypt" and "decrypt". Read @MaartenBodewes first comment above.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk Thank you for your response! What I also dont understand, why isnt it enoug to encrypt with pulic key en decrypt with private key. Ok there can be a man in the middle, but than you use certificates. Why would you still want to sign and verify, I dont see the reason for it..

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate [encryption and signing](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs5430/2015sp/notes/rsa_sign_vs_dec.php). Even mathematically they are similar operations, there are some important differences. I will try to summarize basics

> mesaage and uses his own private key to encrypt the message digest

Actually - person A creates a hash of the content and signs the hash. It means executing a *decryption* operation with signing padding with its private key, creating a signature

> Now person B will make a hash value of the message to compare it to the message digest.

And this is wrong. Whoever (any attacker) could modify/falsify the content and create a valid digest.

Person B

- creates a hash value of the content
- validates the provided signature - encrypts the provided signature with A's public key which should result to the hash and signing padding

> but anyone else can do that too

Signing ensures, that only A could sign the mesage digest, because only with private key you  could "decrypt" - create an output, which after "encryption" could lead to some specific value (digest).

It is as well important to use full specification for RSA operations (PSS padding), not text-book RSA (without nonce and padding). Otherwise if some could trick A to decrypt any input, leading to creating a signature or revealing the private key.

Edit:

> why isnt it enoug to encrypt with pulic key

Encrypting ensures, that only the addressee could decrypt the message, but it doesn't say who is sending the message. (A can believe that only B reads the message, but B may not be sure it is a message from A)

Signing undeniably identifies the sender.  (B can be sure the message is sent by A)

There are some caveats in this approach (signing a directly encrypted message), but details could be better explained in the crypto OS forum.